# I can not consume a service from PHP

Tags: php, service

I am trying to consume a service that I exposed from a project that I have in c #, the problem is that when consuming the service from php I get the following error.
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

Code:

```
function __construct() {

    # data needs to be POSTed to the Play url as JSON.
    # (some code from http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl)
    $data = array("grant_type" => "password", "username" => "Administrador", "password" => "xxxx");
    $data_string = json_encode($data);

    print_r($data_string);

    $ch = curl_init('https://integraciones.intergrupo.com/rest/oauth/token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;        // Outputs the JSON decoded data
}
```

Comment: hm... you send a request to `../oauth/token` but have grant_type "password". Could it be the wrong endpoint for pwd authentication?

Comment: I doubt you need to (or should) json_encode `$data` when sending as form-urlencoded. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code - in the linked example of lornajane they use `application/json`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the solution!

Comment: I'll make it an answer then, feel free to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a header `'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`.
With that you shouldn't json_encode `$data`, but just add the array to POSTFIELDS:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

OR change the header to `'Content-Type: application/json'`